# Does any ordinary object emit radiation due to Unruh effect and equivalence principle?

Tags: hawking-radiation, equivalence-principle, unruh-effect

I am just wondering is there Hawking radiation for any object (that has mass) due to its gravity.
Base on the Unruh effect and equivalence principle, any object should emit Black-body radiation or Hawking radiation. So you can boil a pot of water by putting it close by a massive object.